Plot3D does not show the image of function
I have a functionR1[x_, t_] = -((t^35 x^2)/10333147966386144929666651337523200000000);
I use the following command in Mathematica to show the graph of Function
pic1 = Plot3D[Abs[R1[x, t]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 16], BoxRatios -> {1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}, PlotStyle -> Green]

The Image is not shown

But when I am using the following Function
R2[x_, t_] = - ((t^35*x^2)/10333147966386144929666651337523200000);

I have just removed three zero from the denominator, Mathematica gives the Image of function using same code
pic1 = Plot3D[Abs[R2[x, t]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 14], 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 16], 
  BoxRatios -> {1.5, 1.5, 1.5}, ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green]

The Image of Second Function is

How we obtain the Image of 1st Function. I am using Mathematica 13.3.1

for your first one, if you do Table[Abs[R1[x, t]], {x, 0, 1, .1}, {t, 0, 1, .1}] // Chop then you will see why. It is all zeros https://i.sstatic.net/ophxcsA4.png  it looks like you hit a thresh hold on what Plot3D can show in terms of how small the values can be. For your R2 you did not hit this limit.

You can see this by changing the code to Plot3D[1000*Abs[R1[x, t]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All] and now it shows plot.

Here is your R1 without Chop. You see how small the values are  https://i.sstatic.net/HKIlaSOy.png

Too small. It is recommended to use Log scaling.

The smallest normalized single precision number is:
2^-128 // N

2.93874*10^-39

It looks like Plot3D truncates numbers smaller than same threshold approx. around this number:
 Plot3D[10^-38 2 (x), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]


